# Tips for creating PBR skin material?

Tags: rendering, materials, pbr, subsurface-scattering

So, I've been messing around with skin subsurface scattering shaders for about a day now. I'm roughly following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_kl5UgPIhE) tutorial, by CGBlender, (links to both .blend files at the bottom) with elements from Andrew's [PBR Dielectric Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3wghbZ-Vh4).

[image: Left side is my material, but I've made some edits since rendering. Right side is the material from the tutorial.]

I've almost entirely gone my own way with the material, the main difference being that instead of giving the subsurface scattering nodes different colors, I gave them all the same color, but each has a radius that only scattering certain colors.

Now, for my question: what is the most physically accurate way to mix "layers" of SSS. In other words: I want to know how to mix the different layers in order to create the appearance of layers of skin, fat, and blood. Sidenote: I haven't yet added a third SSS node, so I only have representations for blood and fat, with diffuse acting as the skin. The fat and blood layers are being controlled by a simple factor slider.

P.S. don't hesitate to tell me if I'm doing all of this entirely wrong, and please lead me in the right direction; I'm pretty much winging this.

Any help is appreciated :)

Files:

[CGBlender tutorial file (from the guy's website)](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-920327088737398920.appspot.com/o/CGblender_SSS.zip?alt=media&token=4fb70a66-edd1-4702-8498-3e14905da921)

[My file (google drive) and the textures are the same as the first file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17eCiIZHsvVO8efQctTUPukzvMSIfTk-i)

Comment: Although not Blender-specific, this thread may be of interest to you :) http://www.cgfeedback.com/cgfeedback/showthread.php?t=3776